# Share to Facebook image to use for bar button item in iPhone app

Tags: facebook-ios-sdk

I am building a share-to-Facebook feature in my iPhone app. I'd like to use a suitable bar button item that the user will press for sharing.

Is there a standard .png image I can use, that is recommended or approved by Facebook? Do I have to make it? Or buy it?

I know this isn't a programming question, but my app is close to being ready, except for the fact I don't have a bar button image I can use.

Answer (score 0):

Found it. There are no stupid questions. http://www.facebook.com/brandpermissions/logos.php